# Symfony CLI arguments are interpreted by PHP

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to import a database structure to mapping with Symfony/Doctrine.

I followed the tutorial [here](http://symfony.com/fr/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html) and it gives the command to create mapping files from existing databases:

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:convert xml ./src/Acme/BlogBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/metadata/orm --from-database --force
```

But the PHP interpreter exits instantly:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Option inconnue --from-database in Unknown on line 0
Could not startup.
```

*(`Option inconnue` means unknown option in french)*

I can understand that PHP do not pass the arguments to app/console script.

If I try with [HHVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HipHop_Virtual_Machine), the arguments are sent to the PHP script (so, it runs fine).

PHP version: `PHP 5.5.12-2ubuntu4.1`

**EDIT:** Problem solved, see my answer below. I will accept it tomorrow (StackOverflow limitation).

Comment: Humm... je n'ai encore jamais vu de message d'erreur en français... c'est symfony qui permet ça?

Comment: A mon avis PHP puise dans les locales installées sur l'ordinateur.
Si votre PC est configuré en français vous aurez aussi plus souvent des messages en français, ou comme ici, partiellement en français.

English people: don't stress, our conversation here is not related to the subject ;)

Answer (score 1):

Because of the shebang in the console script, you can omit the php interpreter call in the command line by doing:

```
chmod +x app/console
./app/console doctrine:mapping:convert xml ./src/Acme/BlogBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/metadata/orm --from-database --force
```

or, alternatively, you can do:

```
php app/console -- doctrine:mapping:convert xml ./src/Acme/BlogBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/metadata/orm --from-database --force
```

Please note the separating additional `--` after the script input filename, that tell the php interpreter that each successive argument should be led to the script.

Comment: By default, app/console is executable. Usually I don't prefix my commands with `php`. I just pasted the command from the tutorial. And with or without "php", the result is the same - "option inconnue".
Your second solution seems to work a little better, but now I have a Symfony error: `[RuntimeException] Too many arguments.`

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

```
sudo apt-get purge php5-cli
sudo apt-get install php5-cli
```

It seems that a person [had the same problem](https://serverfault.com/questions/301070/php-cli-error-could-not-startup), and some people suggested that php.ini was missing.

So I reinstalled PHP and now it works perfectly.

If anyone have an explanation for this behaviour, it would be great!

EDIT: Hum, nope, there's a problem. It worked perfectly until I re-added my extensions in php.ini. I just added two lines:

```
 extension=cairo.so
 extension=php_gtk2.so
```

And now it's broken again... :/